# How to wait until a timer stops

Tags: c#, timer, timertask

I need to wait the next line to be waiting until a timer finishes.

```
    public void animation(){
          timer1.start();
          labelStatus.Visibility=true;
    }
```

I want the labelStatus to be visible after the timer1 finished.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fromX = lblMove.Location.X;
        int fromY = lblMove.Location.Y;

        if (fromY > moveToY)
        {
            Y = Y - 5;
            lblMove.Location = new Point(fromX, Y);

        }

        else if (fromY < moveToY)
        {
            Y = Y + 5;
            lblMove.Location = new Point(fromX, Y);
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Put labelStatus.Visibility=true; in the else statement

Comment: Looks like you are waiting for `fromY == moveToY` but that won't necessarily ever be true if you always move by 5 pixels! Not sure what you mean by _I want the labelStatus to be visible_ as you are never hiding it anyway. Also: Timers don't 'finish': You 'stop' them.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I can think of is this

```
public void animation(){  
    timer1.start();
    labelStatus.Visibility=false;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    [...]

    else if (fromY < moveToY)
    {
        Y = Y + 5;
        lblMove.Location = new Point(fromX, Y);
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        labelStatus.Visibility = true;
    }
}
```

This way when you stop the timer you make the label visible. There are many other ways of doing this but this should be simple.

Comment: No I do not want to use this because this is inside a loop and it is a dynamic one

Answer (score 0):

Second method.

Apparently Timer doesn't have a "OnStopped" event to hook to (unless you want to try with dispose). However a Timer has a  `System.Timer.Timer.Enabled` flag for telling you that it's running.

It's not a clean solution, but you could create a new Thread and Poll "timer.Enabled" until it turns false.